# UUID instead of GUID (Oracle to Postgres)

Tags: postgresql, oracle, ora2pg

Is there any chance to have duplicate hexadecimal value while migrating oracle to Postgres (guid to UUID)

I have a table having column which is generate 32 character hexadecimal value by using `sys_guid` function (default oracle sys object). Now I want to migrate Oracle to Postgres but guid is not supported by Postgres but it has UUID instead of guid. Just want to confirm that whether there will be any chance to have duplicate value after migrating oracle to Postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GUID is [a synonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) for UUID.

The UUIDs generated by Oracle can be stored without problems in a column defined as `uuid` in Postgres.

Postgres provides [gen_random_uuid()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-uuid.html) that will generate a V4 UUID.

Comment: Hi , thanks for your comment. But in postgres my column is varchar(32). And I'm inserting value by generating I'd by sys_guid().and i have some previous data in oracle and i have uploaded it into postgres.in future if I'm inserting the Id through the gen_random_UUID (),is there any chance to get duplicate Id in postgres

Comment: You should **not** store a UUID in a `varchar` column, use the `uuid` type. But the chance to get duplicates when using `gen_random_uuid()` are next to none (and essentially the same as when using `sys_guid()`).